# Change max_execution_time on digital ocean server manual deployment

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I deployed my app to digital ocean server but there are error in max execution time out?
My question is how to edit the php.ini max execution time out in digital ocean without droplet created and it is a manual deployment?

I tried different solution like adding user.ini to the root folder and set it to 0 inside the user.ini file. Another solution i tried is locating the php.ini in digital ocean console by typing this command.

`php -i | grep php.ini`

and it gives me the output

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /app/.heroku/php/etc/php Loaded configuration File => /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php.ini`

And when i tried to access the php.ini it says Permission Denied.

Im stucked with almost 3 days of this problem any help or suggestion would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change it from the app using `ini_set`. Here [link to doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: i also tried using ini_set(0) but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to specify the option name. Something like this `ini_set(«max_execution_time »,0) ;`